Getting status 404 error when launching Appium programmatically
After updating Appium to the newer version Appium 1.22.3 I am getting a status 404 error when trying to launch Appium programmatically.
It used to work fine in the older version but now I am kind of not sure why I am getting this error.
public void globalSetup(ITestContext context) throws Exception {
    // Load Props
    loadProperties("appiumTests.properties");

    // Load Secrets, Create the file
    loadSecrets(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/automationSecrets.properties");

    // Get Suite name
    prop.setProperty("SuiteName", context.getName());

    if (getRestartDeviceProperty().equals("true")) {
        DeviceInteractions.rebootDevice(getPlatformData(), getDeviceUdidData(getDeviceNameData()));
    }
    logger.info("Building Appium Server...");
    AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
            .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "info").withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.RELAXED_SECURITY)
            .withLogFile(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/logs/appium.log")).usingAnyFreePort();

    service = builder.build();
    logger.info("The url is" +service);
    logger.info("Appium server is built.");
    logger.info("Starting appium server...");
    service.start();
    logger.info("Appium server started.");
    cleanFileContent("report.txt");

    // Clean TestID file
    prop.setProperty(testRailRunIDProp, "");
}

public URL getServiceUrl() {
    return service.getUrl();

}

And in the set up I am calling the driver like this.
driver = new AndroidDriver(getServiceUrl(), capabilities);

Error that I am getting

[ DEBUG] 2024-05-21 18:07:31.339 [org.testng.log4testng.Logger.debug(Logger.java:82)] - suiteXmlPath: "/Users/subh/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/temp-testng-customsuite.xml"
[ INFO ] 2024-05-21 18:07:32.075 [org.testng.log4testng.Logger.info(Logger.java:112)] - [TestNG] Running:
/Users/subh/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/temp-testng-customsuite.xml


[ INFO ] 2024-05-21 18:07:32.144 [TestHelpers.PropertiesHelper.getRestartDeviceProperty(PropertiesHelper.java:207)] - Loading the 'RestartDevice' Property from the 'appiumTests.properties' file
[ INFO ] 2024-05-21 18:07:32.144 [TestFixtures.BaseTestFixture.globalSetup(BaseTestFixture.java:93)] - Building Appium Server...
[ INFO ] 2024-05-21 18:07:32.245 [TestFixtures.BaseTestFixture.globalSetup(BaseTestFixture.java:100)] - The url isio.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService@45c80312
[ INFO ] 2024-05-21 18:07:32.245 [TestFixtures.BaseTestFixture.globalSetup(BaseTestFixture.java:101)] - Appium server is built.
[ INFO ] 2024-05-21 18:07:32.245 [TestFixtures.BaseTestFixture.globalSetup(BaseTestFixture.java:102)] - Starting appium server...
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.3
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   port: 16292
[Appium]   logFile: /Users/subh/IdeaProjects/tile_mobile_automation/logs/appium.log
[Appium]   loglevel: info
[Appium]   relaxedSecurityEnabled: true
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:16292
[HTTP] --> GET /status
[HTTP] {}
[HTTP] <-- GET /status 404 13 ms - 211
[HTTP]
[HTTP] --> GET /status
[HTTP] {}
[HTTP] <-- GET /status 404 9 ms - 211
[HTTP]


The issue likely arises from a change in Appium's default server path between Appium versions.
In Appium 1.22.3, the path for the status endpoint has changed from /wd/status to just /`.
Here's how to fix it:
Update the URL construction:
Instead of getServiceUrl(), use new URL(getServiceUrl(), "/wd/hub"). This adds the necessary path segment.
Explanation:
getServiceUrl() retrieves the base URL from Appium.
Appending /wd/hub specifies the correct endpoint for the status check in Appium 1.22.3.

I am still getting the same issue even after doing the above changes
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(getServiceUrl(),"/wd/hub"), capabilities);

I was able to resolve this issue by updating the Appium to Appium 2 and also downloading the Appium drivers and changing my driver like this
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(getServiceUrl(),""), capabilities);

